# How to change which resources answers a request from Servlet Filter?

Tags: redirect, jersey, servlet-filters, shiro

I have a `ServletFilter` (which happens to be a `GuiceShiroFilter`) that processes incoming web requests before they go to a Jersey 1.x Resource.

However, in some situations (namely when Shiro finds that the request is not authenticated), I want to change which Jersey resource answers my request, without the resource that otherwise *would* have answered even being able to respond.

Here's what I have (in my Shiro `AuthenticatingFilter`.`onLoginFailure()`):

```
ServletRequest request = ...;
RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("/resource/that/always/responsds/with/a/403");
try {
    disp.forward(request, response);
} catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// this is needed to prevent the woud-be resource from responding as well
return false;
```

The problem of this server-side redirect is that not returning `false` will invoke both my resource for `"/resource/that/always/responsds/with/a/403"` and the original would-be response, and in the best case the response body contains both responses concatenated.

**Is there a way to modify an existing instance of (`Http`)`ServletRequest` from a `Filter` such that later on, only the redirected-to resource can answer?**

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the issue a little bit and I realized that there is little I can do here, given that I don't control how the filter chain is processed further.

In a generic `Filter`, the implementer can wrap the current `ServletRequest` (in `doFilter()` in a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` implementation. This wrapper can then override the request URI. However, this requires that the implementer has control over how the filter chain is continued (which is where the wrapped request can be fed back into the execution path), but this is not the case in my situation, where Shiro controls that.

With Shiro, the filter chain continuation is controlled in `AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal()`, many layers above my own `AuthenticatingFilter` implementation.

So for now, my best bet is to do what I already described above: Invoke another resource - free from filters - by using a `RequestDispatcher` and stop the filter chain by returning `false` at the end of my `AuthenticatingFilter`'s `onLoginFailure()`